# how can add integer from edittext to array In android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

I am using java to code a small program. this program will take data from the keyboard and check the parity of that sequence and this is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edso = findViewById(R.id.so);
    btnchan = findViewById(R.id.btnchan);
    btnle = findViewById(R.id.btnle);
    tvkq=findViewById(R.id.tvkq);
    String n=edso.getText().toString();
    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    arr.add(Integer.parseInt(n));
    Integer[] array = arr.toArray(new Integer[5]);

    btnchan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (int i=0;i< array.length;i++){
                if (array[i]%2==0){
                    tvkq.setText("chăn"+array[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    btnle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (int i=0;i< array.length;i++){
                if (array[i]%2!=0){
                    tvkq.setText("lẽ"+array[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

help me

**i want to use data from edittext to check and display it in textview**

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(mEditText.getText().toString());
arr.add(num);
```

or

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
         int num = Integer.parseInt(s.toString()); 
         arr.add(num);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: mEditText.getText() may be empty

Comment: 'int  n=Integer.parseInt(edso.getText().toString());
        List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();

        arr.add(n);
        Integer[] array = arr.toArray(new Integer[0]);'